# Avoiding gaps of data on edges after clipping a raster?

Tags: qgis, raster, clip, interpolation, boundaries

After using interpolation and clipping the grid I get the result you can see on the picture below. Next to the boundaries there are a lot of gaps caused by the raster cells. These gaps are problematic for me. Is it possible to buffer the result over the boundaries?

[image]

Comment: When you select the **Raster Interpolation** tool, could you set the extent to its current size and then _manually_ increase the values slightly in each dimension? Then with the output, you could **clip** it with a mask layer.

Comment: I guess the problem is the clipping tool. Whatever I do I always get the same result.

Comment: Perhaps you can try using the **Warp (Reproject)** tool (_Raster_ > _Projections_ > _Warp (Reproject)_) and set the masking layer from there? (FYI, I would have upvoted your post but I was trigger-happy today and already reached the limit -_-)

Comment: Thanx for the advice but the result keeps the same....

Comment: Would there be anything problematic about clipping to a larger region?  (I notice that your clipping region and the black polyline you have drawn do not agree, either, which suggests that one or the other is not correctly drawn.)

Answer (score 2):

Since a raster is always a matrix of individual pixels, there's no way to get rid of the zig-zag along the edges, when you clip on an angle. However, if you can increase the resolution of the raster (interpolation to a higher resolution) then the gaps will be small enough that it should not be a problem.

Comment: In Arc you can use a filter (close to the saga simple filter). After filtering the raster is a little bit increased (bufferd). Is this possible in QGIS?